# Viewing events from SQL table by month in a list view on website

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am attempting to create a list view on my website which shows events from a table.

This is how my table looks like:

```
Event Name | Event Description | Starts At | Ends At
```

There are several catches though:

1. The list should show events by month from the database. I will have a drop-down list above the list which contains all the months of the year. When the user selects a particular month, he should be able to view all the events uploaded in the database in that month in the list.
2. The list should also have the feature of being exported into an Excel format document which will contain the list of these events.

I googled extensively and tried building this on my own but I keep getting errors. I don't want anyone giving me the code (you don't have to my job for me) but I would be grateful if you could give me direction and guidelines as to how I can do this.

I am new to ASP.NET so please use Muggle words. :D

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the code you've tried so far?

Comment: When and what errors you are getting?

Comment: Is extra credit awarded for solutions that correctly handle events that span one or more months? Are you having trouble selecting the correct data, exporting in Excel format, or both?

Comment: FWIW, assuming that you can determine the first date of the target month (`@TargetDate`), you can select `WHERE StartsAt < DateAdd( month, 1, @TargetDate ) and EndsAt >= @TargetDate`. ("If the event starts before the end of the target month and ends after the start of the target month.") This correctly finds any event that overlaps the target month: contained within the target month, overlaps the start of the target month, overlaps the end of the target month or contains the entire target month.

Comment: I deleted the code but I essentially created a list view table using this tutorial: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5e30de78-fc68-4e1e-afdc-96f829ed5025/how-to-display-a-table-from-sql-into-a-c-form)
I am struggling with creating a dropdown list that works. I am getting the table right but the events aren't refreshed as and when I change months in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for manipulating spreadsheets and as far as getting the `Event`s for a specific month (i am guessing specific year too) then you can do something like this in SQL (Where @Month & @Year are your parameters):

```
SELECT *
FROM Events
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Starts_At) = @Month
AND DATEPART(MONTH, Starts_At) = @Year
```